# Shift R Markdown title to the second page

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, cpu-word

I have created a Rmd file and want to shift the title of the document to the second page instead of the first page, which is done by default.

Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a .tex file in the Yaml header:

-put everything into the tex file you want to have before the title page of your rmd. Done.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "user12256545"
date: "9 11 2020"
output: 
  html_document:
           includes:
            before_body: firstpage.tex 
---
```